# d3.js Series Circle chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am looking to create a chart like this -- that shows the various different relationships in a horizontal plane.

[image]

So I envision the data will look like this

```
[{
    "name": "Twitter",
    "vistsperday": "15 billion",
    "employeecount": 450
}, {
    "name": "Facebook",
    "vistsperday": "5 billion",
    "employeecount": 2000
}, {
    "name": "Google",
    "vistsperday": "5 billion",
    "employeecount": 25000
}, {
    "name": "Netflix",
    "vistsperday": "10 billion",
    "employeecount": 2200
}, {
    "name": "Ebay",
    "vistsperday": "8 billion",
    "employeecount": 17700
}, {
    "name": "Klout",
    "vistsperday": "2 billion",
    "employeecount": 45
}]
```

I have started a jsfiddle here.
deriving from https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/  - three little circles
* Latest fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1425/

- The problem I am having first - is all of the data in the array has to be different values otherwise the circle won't render
- How to contract/squash the circles closer together -I've tried adjusting the cx formula but to no affect.

here is the current structure of the code from the latest fiddle.

//code

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

  var rawData = [{
    "name": "Twitter",
    "vistsperday": "15 billion",
    "employeecount": 450
  }, {
    "name": "Facebook",
    "vistsperday": "5 billion",
    "employeecount": 2000
  }, {
    "name": "Google",
    "vistsperday": "5 billion",
    "employeecount": 25000
  }, {
    "name": "Netflix",
    "vistsperday": "10 billion",
    "employeecount": 2200
  }, {
    "name": "Ebay",
    "vistsperday": "8 billion",
    "employeecount": 17700
  }, {
    "name": "Klout",
    "vistsperday": "2 billion",
    "employeecount": 45
  }];



  var width = 700;
  var height = 500;
  var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 100,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 100
  }

  //serieschart
  var svg = d3.select(".serieschart").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "serieschart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var bluedata = [5000,2000,2000,1600,701,1603];

  //blue layer
    var bluelayer = svg.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "bluelayer")

  var bluecircle = bluelayer.selectAll("circle")
    .data(bluedata);

  bluecircle.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "blue")
    .attr("cy", 60)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return (i * 60) + 10;
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d);
    });

  bluecircle.exit().remove();


  var golddata = [32, 57, 293,31, 455, 296];
    //gold layer
    var goldlayer = svg.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "goldlayer")

  var goldcircle = goldlayer.selectAll("circle")
    .data(golddata);

  goldcircle.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "gold")
    .attr("cy", 60)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return (i * 60) + 10;
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d);
    });

  goldcircle.exit().remove();



});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem:

```
 var bluecircle = bluelayer.selectAll("circle")
    .data(bluedata);
```

otherwise when you get to

```
 .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return (i * 100) + 10;
    })
```

the elements that are the same will be represented once in the cx function.

For the second problem, edit your cx e.g. like this:

```
.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return (i * 80) + 10;
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ky4wvgm/

Good luck! :)

Comment: return (i * 60) + 10;  -- I think the goal would be to reduce from 100

Comment: var bluecircle = bluelayer.selectAll("circle")
    .data(bluedata, function(d) {
      return d;
    });   -- change this to    var bluecircle = bluelayer.selectAll("circle")
    .data(bluedata);

Comment: You mean you want to reduce dynamically and differently for each circle the cx? Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: I think I mean -- make this more dynamic -- and rather than just guessing at hardcoding 80 or 60 - find out what it should be and what it likely means

Comment: my next issue would be adding labels and pointers -- got an issue getting these working now -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1426/

Comment: (thinking about the dynamic cx ) For the labels, from what I can see: `var labels = labellayer.selectAll("text")
    .data(datalabels);` and after that I get an error: ir and r are not defined.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1427/  -- I have the labels coming onto the page --- but how to map them according to the circles

Answer (score 0):

I've hooked into place one raw data source to try and control the application.

http://jsfiddle.net/59bunh8u/23/
[image]
I try altering some of the values -- in-versing them almost to see how the chart adapts - but it starts to tear with the pointers.
http://jsfiddle.net/59bunh8u/24/
[image]

```
M-4.78125,125L44.78125,125 75.50572494064927,60
```

when I altered the path to reduce the L coordinate it nearly fixes the error - its almost like the L part of the path is being plotted incorrectly.

```
M-4.78125,125L4.78125,125 75.50572494064927,60
```

Comment: I tried using "V" instead of  "L" but couldn't make it work properly for the time being. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/59bunh8u/25/

Comment: It does have a weird behavior when I try adjusting the values of layer1value etc... I can't figure it out yet.

Comment: @mkaran  - what behavior do you see -- I was finding circles in the wrong place being painted..

Comment: yes, this and that  the last two labels (Google and Netflix) are not painted correctly, but I still cannot figure this out.

Comment: stable -- http://jsfiddle.net/59bunh8u/27/  - not stable http://jsfiddle.net/59bunh8u/26/

Comment: @mkaran got another chart puzzle for you man - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153035/d3-dougnut-bubble-pie-chart

Comment: Hmm the [stable one](http://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/59bunh8u/28) also has the issue.. I'll check it out during the day along with the other puzzle!

Comment: @mkaran -- yeah no sorry -- they are both the same chart -- just the difference in data

Comment: Could you please take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/e9hrk3kv/1/ I think it works more consistently but there are some issues. Also, I am not sure about the data and the scaling of the circles. (I've added extra labels so that it is visible what the value of the circles are)

Comment: @mkaran - I've reversed the value quantities in the first two pieces of data -- http://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/e9hrk3kv/1/ -- but the circles don't seem to batch correctly -- its like the "MASTER" circle is taken as godsend for the position of the circles from each other

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure I understand..Could you take a look at these: this is with reversed the first two items http://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/e9hrk3kv/2 and this is with reversed the first two item values http://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/e9hrk3kv/3

Comment: And this with reversed layer1value and 2 for the 1st item http://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/e9hrk3kv/4

Comment: Oh you mean the ratio of the other circles that getCircleSize return...

Comment: I've changed the getCircleSize a bit http://jsfiddle.net/mkaran/e9hrk3kv/5  even though I believe a more consistent thing to do would be something like this `layerSet.push(parseInt(getPercentage(layerArray[i], meansPerGroup[0])*60, 10));`

Comment: @mkaran - how far did we get with this. Is this the latest variant? difficult to remember which one is stable

Comment: @mkaran -- I am moving this into a new question - see others can help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306307/d3-js-checking-count-series-chart

Comment: @mkaran -- there is a bounty out man - to continue this work over here -- this time a more specific foursquare like data set -- venue, checkins, count -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306307/d3-js-checking-count-series-chart