# d3.js an Inverse bubble chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I am interested in creating something like this. Usually we see people drawing a bubble - I am keen to draw the space to represent the bubble. I would perhaps place this mask/chart in a shared component -- that is conjoined only by a background image -- so maybe embed this in a bootstrap part like col-md-8.

I've added the the subtraction mask -- and some label/pointer stuff - but its not rendering.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1525/

```
var data = [{
    "label": "My Property Value over 3 yrs.",
    "value": "148",
    "direction": "up"
}]
```

so the json for this may be something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function maskMaker(el) {

    var backcolor = $(el).data("color");
    var backopacity = $(el).data("opacity");

    // Set the main elements for the series chart
    var svgroot = d3.select($(el)[0]).append("svg");
    var mask = svgroot
      .append("defs")
      .append("mask")
      .attr("id", "myMask");

    mask.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", "1200px")
      .attr("height", 500)
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("opacity", backopacity);

    mask.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 550)
      .attr("cy", 250)
      .attr("r", 150);



    var data = [{
      label: "text",
      x: 222,
      y: 222
    }]

    //__labels 
    var labels = mask.append("g")
      .attr("class", "labels")

    //__ enter
    var labels = labels.selectAll("text")
      .data(data);

    labels.enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

    //__ update            
    labels
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.label;
      })
      .each(function(d) {
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        d.sx = d.x - bbox.width / 2 - 2;
        d.ox = d.x + bbox.width / 2 + 2;
        d.sy = d.oy = d.y + 5;
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(300)

    labels
      .transition()
      .duration(300)

    //__ exit
    labels.exit().remove();
    //__labels         
    //__labels 


    //__pointers
    var pointers = mask.append("g")
      .attr("class", "pointers")

    pointers.append("defs").append("marker")
      .attr("id", "circ")
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("refX", 3)
      .attr("refY", 3)
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 3)
      .attr("cy", 3)
      .attr("r", 3);

    var pointers = pointers.selectAll("path.pointer")
      .data(data);

    //__ enter
    pointers.enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "pointer")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)");

    //__ update
    pointers
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        if (d.cx > d.ox) {
          return "M" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + "L" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
        } else {
          return "M" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + "L" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
        }
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(300)

    pointers
      .transition()
      .duration(300)

    //__ exit
    pointers.exit().remove();
    //__pointers    



    var svg = svgroot
      .attr("class", "series")
      .attr("width", "1200px")
      .attr("height", "500px")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")

    var rect = svg
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", "750px")
      .attr("height", 500)
      .attr("mask", "url(#myMask)")
      .style("fill", backcolor);

  }

  //var el = $(".mask"); //selector

  $('[data-role="mask"]').each(function(index) {
    console.log("test")
    maskMaker(this);
  });
});
```

---

latest answer

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1535/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do several things:

1. In SVG DOM have the label and the pointer **after** the rectangle with the mask (or the rectangle itself before them). This will make them topmost. There is no z-index in SVG.
2. Add a declaration of the marker to the same 'defs' node at the beginning of SVG
3. Set pointer target values d.cx and d.cy (in the example below I set them to ordinary values)
4. Implement enter-update-exit pattern differently. In your example code with comments '__ update' will only be executed for existing elements in the selection, whereas it is empty on first run. See https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218 on how to merge operations on just added elements and already existing ones.

   ```
   labels.enter()
     .append("text")
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

   //__ update
   //labels

     .attr("x", function(d) {
       return d.x;
     })
     ...
   ```

A working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1528/

Comment: I've updated it - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1529/ -- is there a better way to make the coordinates more dynamic to the gap - so it will hit the side of the bubble

Comment: Yes, you can use the same mask approach. In the example below you can just point the line into the center of a bubble and hide everything else by a clone of a mask applied earlier (but with opacity of rectangle set to 1) http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1530/

Comment: what if you want to animate the bubble? have it grow in size based on part of the data

Comment: -- I've updated the jsfiddle to make it more data driven - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1533/ -- I am trying to add the white text label in the center

Comment: invisiblebubble.enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return "200";
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return "200";
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return "200";
      })

Comment: --- latest jsfiddle - with the white label in the middle -- http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1534/

Comment: You can create a separate question on animation, unless it already exists (there is a lot of tutorials on this topic too). You need to animate a circle inside a mask, if I understood right. Please also mark this answer as accepted if you think so. You can also contact me using my personal details to perform this and related jobs on a contract-based scheme.

Comment: there is a bounty on this one -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306307/d3-js-checking-count-series-chart