# d3 javascript series chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, series

[image]

I am trying to create this particular d3 application where a series of data can be dynamically displayed like this. Each segment contains two pieces of data.

The first step is to print the circles so there is sufficient space between the series but also the largest circle is always under the smaller circle.

//**version 3 -- with correct labels and legend--**
http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/33/

//******version 2 fiddle******
http://jsfiddle.net/1oka61mL/10/

[image]

-- How to set the diagonal labels properly - same angles, aligned properly?
-- Add legend?
-- Mask the bottom pointers in an opposite color then continue the line in a different color?

//******Latest Jsfiddle******
http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/26/

```
var width = 600;
var height = 400;
var svg = d3.select('svg').attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

//Count
//Checkins
//Popularity

var data = [{
  "name": "Twitter",
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "label": "Count",
    "value": 200
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Checkins",
    "value": 1000
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Popularity",
    "value": 30
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Facebook",
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "label": "Count",
    "value": 500
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Checkins",
    "value": 300
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Popularity",
    "value": 740
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Ebay",
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "label": "Count",
    "value": 4000
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Checkins",
    "value": 1000
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Popularity",
    "value": 40
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Foursquare",
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "label": "Count",
    "value": 2000
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Checkins",
    "value": 3000
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Popularity",
    "value": 4500
  }]
}];


var outerRadius = [];
// organise the data. 
// Insert indices and sort items in each series
// keep a running total of max circle size in each series
// for later positioning
var x = 0;
var totalWidth = d3.sum(
  data.map(function(series) {
    series.items.forEach(function(item, i) {
      item.index = i;
    });
    series.items.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.value - a.value;
    });
    var maxr = Math.sqrt(series.items[0].value);
    outerRadius.push(maxr);
    x += maxr;
    series.xcentre = x;
    x += maxr;
    return maxr * 2;
  })
);

// make scales for position and colour
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, totalWidth]).range([0, width]);
//var colScale = d3.scale.category10();

function colores_google(n) {
  var colores_g = ["#f7b363", "#448875", "#c12f39", "#2b2d39", "#f8dd2f"];
  return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
}


// add a group per series, position the group according to the values and position scale  we calculated above
var groups = svg.selectAll("g").data(data);
groups.enter().append("g");
groups.attr("transform", function(d) {
  return ("translate(" + d.xcentre + ",0)");
});


// then add circles per series, biggest first as items are sorted
// colour according to index (the property we inserted previously so we can
// keep track of their original position in the series)
var circles = groups.selectAll("circle").data(function(d) {
  return d.items;
}, function(d) {
  return d.index;
});
circles.enter().append("circle").attr("cy", height / 2).attr("cx", 0);

circles
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return Math.sqrt(d.value);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colores_google(d.index);
  });



var labelsgroups = svg.selectAll("text").data(data);
labelsgroups.enter().append("text");
labelsgroups
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    d.y = 300;
    d.cy = 200;
    return 300;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    d.x = d.xcentre;
    d.cx = d.xcentre;
    return d.xcentre;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .each(function(d) {
    var bbox = this.getBBox();
    d.sx = d.x - bbox.width / 2 - 2;
    d.ox = d.x + bbox.width / 2 + 2;
    d.sy = d.oy = d.y + 5;
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle");



var pointersgroups = svg.selectAll("path.pointer").data(data);
pointersgroups.enter().append("path");
pointersgroups
  .attr("class", "pointer")
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)");

pointersgroups
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return "M" + (d.xcentre) + "," + (d.oy - 25) + "L" + (d.xcentre) + "," + (d.sy - 25) + " " + d.xcentre + "," + (d.cy);
  })



function fetchValue(items, label) {
  for (i = 0; i <= items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].label == label) {
      return items[i].value;
    }
  }
}


function fetchRadius(items, label) {
  for (i = 0; i <= items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].label == label) {
      return Math.sqrt(items[i].value);
    }
  }
}

/*
var labels1groups = svg.selectAll(".label1").data(data);
labels1groups.enter().append("text");
labels1groups
  .attr("class", "label1")
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    d.y = 100;
    d.cy = 100;
    return 100;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    d.x = d.xcentre;
    d.cx = d.xcentre+50;
    return d.xcentre+50;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return fetchValue(d.items, "Count");
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
            return "translate(" + (15 * i) + "," + (i * 45) + ") rotate(-45)";

  })
  .each(function(d) {
    var bbox = this.getBBox();
    d.sx = d.x - bbox.width / 2 - 2;
    d.ox = d.x + bbox.width / 2 + 2;
    d.sy = d.oy = d.y ;
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "left");

*/


var gridSize = 100;

var labels1groups = svg.selectAll(".label2")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return fetchValue(d.items, "Count");
    //return d; 
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {

    d.x = i * gridSize + 50;
    d.cx = i * gridSize + 50;

    return i * gridSize;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    d.y = 105;
    d.cy = 50;
    return 0;
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)" +
      "rotate(-45 " + ((i + 0.5) * gridSize) + " " + (-6) + ")";
  })
  .each(function(d) {
    var bbox = this.getBBox();
    d.sx = d.x - bbox.width / 2 - 2;
    d.ox = d.x + bbox.width / 2 + 2;
    d.sy = d.oy = d.y;
  })
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return ((i >= 8 && i <= 16) ?
      "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" :
      "timeLabel mono axis");
  });




var pointers1groups = svg.selectAll("path.pointer1").data(data);
pointers1groups.enter().append("path");
pointers1groups
  .attr("class", "pointer1")
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)");

pointers1groups
  .attr("d", function(d, i) {

    //d.y = outerRadius[i];
    //d.y = d.oy - d.cy;
    //fetchRadius(d.items, "Count");    

    //(d.xcentre+100)
    // + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy

    //return "M "+ (d.xcentre) +" 25 ,L "+ dist +" 75";

    return "M" + (d.xcentre) + "," + (d.y + d.oy - fetchRadius(d.items, "Count") - 10) + "L" + (d.xcentre + 80) + "," + d.cy;


  })
```

//Older Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/59bunh8u/51/

```
var rawData = [{
    "name": "Twitter",
    "items" : [
        {
            "label" : "15 billion",
            "unit" : "per day",
            "value" : 1500
        },
        {
            "label" : "450 checkins",
            "unit" : "per day",
            "value" : 450
        }
    ]
}, 
{               
    "name": "Facebook",
    "items" : [
        {
            "label" : "5 billion",
            "unit" : "per day",
            "value" : 5000
        },
        {
            "label" : "2000 checkins",
            "unit" : "per day",
            "value" : 2000
        }
    ]
}];


$.each(rawData, function(index, value) {
    var total = 0;
    var layerSet = [];
    var ratios = [25, 100];

    $.each(value["items"], function(i, v) {
        total += v["value"];
    });

    value["total"] = total;
});



var w = $this.data("width");
var h = $this.data("height");

var el = $this;

var margin = {
    top: 65,
    right: 90,
    bottom: 5,
    left: 150
};

var svg = d3.select(el[0]).append("svg")
    .attr("class", "series")
    .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var defs = svg.append("svg:defs");


$.each(rawData, function(i, v) {
    circleDraw(i, v["items"]);
});



//calculates where each element should be placed
function calculateDistance (d, i, items) {
    var dcx = 0;
    for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
      dcx += Math.sqrt(items[k].value);
    }
    return dcx + 10 * i;
}

function getPercentage(value, total) {
    return ((value / total) * 100);
}

function circleDraw(index, data){
    data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseFloat(b.value) - parseFloat(a.value);
    });

    var circlelayer = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "circlelayer");

    var circle = circlelayer.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data);

    circle.enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {
            if (i == 0) {
              return "blue";
            }
            return "gold";
        })
        .attr("cy", 60)
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
            return calculateDistance(d, index, data);
        })
        .attr("r", function(d, i) {
            return Math.sqrt(d.value);
        });

    circle.exit().remove();
}
```

Comment: I am having issues trying to draw just the blue circles in sequence - needing to nest the series - plotting circles next to each other based on the radius. http://jsfiddle.net/59bunh8u/52/

Comment: Am I missing something? There is not even a question in your post. What did you actually offer the bounty on? The only purpose I can see, is to avoid close votes. You have brought this same project up in six questions in the last two days, none of which with a positive score and the overall score being -11! This might even earn you a [question ban](/help/question-bans) anytime soon. Don't get me wrong, this might be an interesting problem, but, please, take a step back, revisit your questions and rephrase them into something legit for the site.

Comment: I am more concerned about solving a particular problem - then garnishing the negative reputation. I have tried to ask the question in various steps and focus on various parts of the problem - tried breaking it down in steps so to speak to resolve one problem at a time.

Comment: The question here - was to revisit adding the diagonal labels correctly - I will add the question mark appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I've managed to get the diagonal markers and pointers in alignment, pointing to the correct circle colors to represent that set. I am keen to fine tune this chart and have more control over the padding and chart width/height parameters. The chart looks stable but would be keen to test it with different values and sized data sets.

/**LATEST**/
http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/33/

```
var width = 760;
var height = 400;

var svg = d3.select('#serieschart')
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

//Count
//Checkins
//Popularity

var data = [{
  "name": "Twitter",
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "label": "Count",
    "value": 200
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Checkins",
    "value": 1000
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Popularity",
    "value": 30
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Facebook",
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "label": "Count",
    "value": 500
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Checkins",
    "value": 300
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Popularity",
    "value": 740
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Ebay",
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "label": "Count",
    "value": 4000
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Checkins",
    "value": 1000
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Popularity",
    "value": 40
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Foursquare",
  "items": [{
    "id": 0,
    "label": "Count",
    "value": 2000
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Checkins",
    "value": 3000
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "Popularity",
    "value": 4500
  }]
}];



var legend_group = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("width", 80)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "legendsection")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,30)");

var legend = legend_group.selectAll("circle").data(data[0].items);

legend.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 70)
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return 15 * i;
  })
  .attr("r", 7)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colores_google(i);
  });

legend.exit().remove();





var legendtext = legend_group.selectAll("text").data(data[0].items);

legendtext.enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "labels")
  .attr("dy", function(d, i) {
    return 15 * i;
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return "start";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.label;
  });

legendtext.exit().remove();

var m = [80, 20, 20, 10];
var w =+ width - m[0];
var h =+ height - m[1];

var chart = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "serieschart")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var outerRadius = [];
// organise the data. 
// Insert indices and sort items in each series
// keep a running total of max circle size in each series
// for later positioning
var x = 0;
var totalWidth = d3.sum(
  data.map(function(series) {
    series.items.forEach(function(item, i) {
      item.index = i;
    });
    series.items.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.value - a.value;
    });
    var maxr = Math.sqrt(series.items[0].value);
    outerRadius.push(maxr);
    x += maxr;
    series.xcentre = x;
    x += maxr;
    return maxr * 2;
  })
);

// make scales for position and colour
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, totalWidth]).range([0, w]);
//var colScale = d3.scale.category10();

function colores_google(n) {
  var colores_g = ["#f7b363", "#448875", "#c12f39", "#2b2d39", "#f8dd2f"];
  return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
}

function fetchValue(items, label) {
  for (i = 0; i <= items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].label == label) {
      return items[i].value;
    }
  }
}

function fetchRadius(items, label) {
  for (i = 0; i <= items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].label == label) {
      return Math.sqrt(items[i].value);
    }
  }
}


// add a group per series, position the group according to the values and position scale  we calculated above
var groups = chart.selectAll("g.seriesGroup").data(data);
var newGroups = groups.enter().append("g").attr("class", "seriesGroup");
newGroups.append("text")
  .attr("class", "seriesName")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
newGroups.append("line")
  .attr("class", "seriesName")
  .attr("y1", h - 40)
  .attr("y2", h / 2);
newGroups.append("text")
  .attr("class", "datumValue")
  .attr("y", 10)
  //.attr("transform", "rotate(-45)")
;
newGroups.append("g").attr("class", "circleGroup");
newGroups.append("g").attr("class", "datumLine")
  .append("line")
  .attr("class", "datumValue")
  .attr("y2", 40);

var focus = "Count";
groups.attr("transform", function(d) {
  return "translate(" + scale(d.xcentre) + ",0)";
});

groups.select("text.seriesName")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .attr("y", h - 20);

groups.select("text.datumValue")
  .text(function(d) {
    return fetchValue(d.items, focus);
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + ((h / 2) - 20 - scale(fetchRadius(d.items, focus))) + ",20) rotate(-45)";
  });

groups.select("line.datumValue")
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return (h / 2) - scale(fetchRadius(d.items, focus));
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return (h / 2) - scale(fetchRadius(d.items, focus) + 20);
  });

// then add circles per series, biggest first as items are sorted
// colour according to index (the property we inserted previously so we can
// keep track of their original position in the series)
var circles = groups
  .select(".circleGroup")
  .selectAll("circle").data(function(d) {
    return d.items;
  }, function(d) {
    return d.index;
  });
circles.enter().append("circle").attr("cy", h / 2).attr("cx", 0);

circles
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return scale(Math.sqrt(d.value));
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colores_google(d.index);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could drawn the lines:

```
groups.append("line")
  .attr("class", "pointer1")
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("y1", height / 2)
  .attr("x2", 0)
  .attr("y2",height - 10);

  var linesG = svg.selectAll(".slines").data(data)
                            .enter().append("g")
              .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return ("translate(" + d.xcentre + "," + height/2 +") rotate(-45)");
              });

  linesG.append("line")
    .attr("class", "pointer1")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 150)
    .attr("y2", 0);

  linesG.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
        return fetchValue(d.items, "Count");
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
     .attr("y", -5)
     .attr("x", 150);
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1oka61mL/5/)

Comment: I've updated it - to reduce the height on the bottom labels - cheers man - http://jsfiddle.net/1oka61mL/7/

Comment: There are two more pieces left -- 
-- Add legend?
-- Mask the bottom pointers in an opposite color then continue the line in a different color?

Comment: The pointers are no longer hitting the outer edge of the circles colors - that was resolved in the first demo --- return "M" + (d.xcentre) + "," + (d.y + d.oy - fetchRadius(d.items, "Count") - 10) + "L" + (d.xcentre + 80) + "," + d.cy;

Comment: Why are you appending new `<svg>` elements?Shouldn't it be a `<g>` element?

Comment: Don't you start out with an svg element and then append the g elements?

Comment: @TheOldCounty: No, you only need one `<svg>`. Then you add `<g>` if you want to group elements in order to apply the same transform.

Comment: Thank you for your help Marcelo -- take a look at the example below -- if you can improve on the latest code